# Не срабатывает команда "zip" в os.system

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

Учу питон с помощью книги A byte of python. Дошла уже до раздела решение задач. Там есть вот такой код:

```
import os
import time
# 1. Файлы и каталоги, которые необходимо скопировать, собираются в список.
source = ['"C://Users/IVANINBOX/Documents/"', 'C://Users//IVANINBOX/Code']
# Заметьте, что для имён, содержащих пробелы, необходимо использовать
# двойные кавычки внутри строки.
# 2. Резервные копии должны храниться в основном каталоге резерва.
target_dir = 'C://Users/IVANINBOX/Backup' # Подставьте ваш путь.
# 3. Файлы помещаются в zip-архив.
# 4. Именем для zip-архива служит текущая дата и время.
target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'
# 5. Используем команду "zip" для помещения файлов в zip-архив
zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))
# Запускаем создание резервной копии
print(zip_command)
if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print('Резервная копия успешно создана в', target)
else:
    print('Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ')
```

В выводе получается:

```
zip -qr C://Users/IVANINBOX/Backup\20200824120643.zip 
"C://Users/IVANINBOX/Documents/" C://Users//IVANINBOX/Code
"zip" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.
Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ
```

Именно с такими непонятными знаками...
Когда я вставляю в коммандную строку выведенную команду `zip_command`,(ее я получила с помощью `print(zip_command)`) все срабатывает, и Архив сохздается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так?

Comment: Тут кракозябры, думаю, из-за разных кодировок консоли и питона. А как работает команда `zip -qr`? Кст, для разделения путей либо используйте везде `os.sep`, либо везде используйте `/`, т.к. в винде `os.sep` это `\\`, а лучше для составления путей использовать нормализацию или `pathlib.Path`. А для выполнения внешних команд `os.system` подходит, но у него есть более лучший аналог -- `subprocess`, который позволит, например, получить вывод внешней программы в байтах и привести его к правильной кодировки, чтобы не видеть кракозябры

Comment: Если этот код из книги, то лучше этой книгой не пользоваться. Как минимум не для изучения Python ;)

Comment: Кст, могу поспорить, что в тех кракозябрах написано `"zip" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.` :D

Comment: @gil9red Я уверена, что нет, ибо в командной строке команда `zip` работает

Comment: @НаташаПухова, неа, есть разница, если приложения `zip.exe` не будет в папке активной директории (обычно это папка с скриптом). Попробуйте использовать модуль `import subprocess` с `shell=True`, это будет тоже самое что вызов из консоли, пример: `subprocess.call(zip_command, shell=True)`

Comment: Вообще, в методы `subprocess` правильнее будет передавать команды разделяя параметры, чтобы он сам правильно их составил (например, для случаев с пробелами): `subprocess.call(["zip", "-qr", 'C:/Users/IVANINBOX/Backup', "C:/Users/IVANINBOX/Documents/", "C:/Users/IVANINBOX/Code"], shell=True)`

Answer (score 1):

Гадать можно долго, но начать надо с элементарной обработки ошибки. В доке на *os.system()* читаем:

> On Windows, the return value is that returned by the system shell
> after running command.

Значит, для начала нужно немного подправить Ваш код. К примеру, так:

```
error = os.system(zip_command)
if error == 0:
    print('Резервная копия успешно создана в', target)
else:
    print('Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ')
    print('Error = ', error)
```

И посмотрите, что означает напечатанный код ошибки. Возможно, это сразу пиведёт Вас к решению проблемы.

И ещё... Мне не понятен вот этот участок кода:

```
source = ['"C://Users/IVANINBOX/Documents/"', 'C://Users//IVANINBOX/Code']
```

Почему первый элемент списка в двойной паре '"..."', а второй - в одинарной '...' ? В этом есть какой-то смысл?

```
Вставляю текст из книги:
# 1. Файлы и каталоги, которые необходимо скопировать, собираются в список.
source = ['"C:\\My Documents"', 'C:\\Code']
# Заметьте, что для имён, содержащих пробелы, необходимо использовать
# двойные кавычки внутри строки.
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло указание полного пути к GnuWin32:

```
zip_command = r'""C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\zip.exe" -r {0} {1}"'.format(target, ' '.join(source))
```

Альтернатива, если делать через 7-Zip:

```
zip_command = r'""C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip -ssw -mx5 -r0 {0} {1}"'.format(target, ' '.join(source))
```

Полный код:

```
import os
import time

source = [r'C:\byteofpy\notes']

target_dir = r'C:\byteofpy\backup'

target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'

if not os.path.exists(target_dir):
    os.mkdir(target_dir)

zip_command = r'""C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\zip.exe" -r {0} {1}"'.format(target, ' '.join(source))

print('Zip command is:')
print(zip_command)
print('Running:')
if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print('\nSuccessful backup to', target)
else:
    print('\nBackup FAILED')
```