# Не работает команда zip в os.system

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import os
import time

source = [r'D:\code']

target_dir = r'D:\Backup'

target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'

if not os.path.exists(target_dir):
    os.mkdir(target_dir)

zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))

print('Zip command is:')
print(zip_command)
print('Running:')
if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print('\nSuccessful backup to', target)
else:
    print('\nBackup FAILED')
```

В выводе получается:

```
C:\Users\Gaguman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe D:\python\project1\backupver2.py 
Zip command is:
zip -qr D:\Backup\20230506223225.zip D:\code
Running:
"zip" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Backup FAILED
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1169654/Не-срабатывает-команда-zip-в-os-system
https://superuser.com/questions/201371/create-zip-folder-from-the-command-line-windows